# bash: emacs: command not found (on windows 10)

Tags: windows, macos, git-bash

I'm new using git and I have a problem when I put this command on git bash (on windows 10):

`$ emacs config`

. I have the next result:
`bash: emacs: command not found`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the folder, where the `emacs` executable file is located,
to the `%PATH%` system environment variable
the step-by-step procedure you can find e.g. here:
`https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/`